# unordered_map to have three elements

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I am trying to have three elements in an `unordered_map`. I tried the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>

typedef boost::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int>> mymap;
mymap m;

int main(){
//std::unordered_map<int, std::pair<int, int> > m;
m.insert({3, std::make_pair(1,1)});
m.insert({4, std::make_pair(5,1)});
for (auto& x: m)
    std::cout << x.first << ": "<< x.second << std::endl;

}
```

but I get many errors in the print statement something like

> ‘std::pair’ is not derived from ‘const std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>’
>        std::cout << x.first << ": "<< x.second << std::endl;

Comment: Why not create a structure and add that instead of the pair? I think code would be more readable.

Comment: The insert is ok, because that is where I see a problem. It should be m.insert(3, std::make_pair(1,1));  Without {}

Comment: The title says "unordered map to have three elements".  I only see two elements in the code though.  Or do you mean that a map which maps an integer to a pair of integers has a value type with three ints in it?

Comment: @MartinBonner I mean a key have two ints as values

Comment: @DragosPop Does `{}` have any side effect

Comment: I checked, I was wrong. Well, it does have a side effect in runtime, I debugged in VS 2013 and it creates an intermediary pair. but other than that it is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem in your printing statement. It should be like this:

```
std::cout << x.first << ": "<< x.second.first << ","<< x.second.second  << std::endl;
_______________________________^^^^^^^^^^^^^^__________^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^_______________
```

You can not just print `std::pair` directly. You need to print each item separately.

There is no `ostream& operator<<` overload for `std::pair` but there is one for `int`.