# How to make two or more elements in bimap as key

Tags: c++, boost-bimap

I would like to know if it is possible to insert two or more elements in `bimap` as key. I have a minimal example of `bimap` with one element key

```
#include <boost/bimap.hpp>
#include <boost/bimap/multiset_of.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::set_of<int>,boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int> > bimap;
  bimap numbers;

  numbers.insert({1, 1});
  numbers.insert({2, 1});
  numbers.insert({3, 8});
  auto it = numbers.left.find(1);


  std::cout << it->first << ":" << it->second << std::endl;
}
```

Now can I have something like

```
typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::set_of<int>,boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int, int > > bimap;
bimap numbers;
numbers.insert({1, 1, 5});
numbers.insert({2, 1, 1});
```

Comment: Sorry, I feel dumb, but what do you mean by "two elements"? Don't you blatantly have *three* elements inserted into the map?

Comment: @KerrekSB Oh!! sorry if I didn't put it well. I mean http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41675259/unordered-map-to-have-three-elements

Comment: No, wait, please make your question self-contained. I don't want to go on a wild goose chase for meaning. I already do that in my day job.

Comment: @KerrekSB I want to have one unique key that I  have with `boost::bimaps::set_of<int>` other key (not strictly unique) that I have with  `boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int>`. I wounder if I can make one more integer entry i.e something like `boost::bimaps::multiset_of<int, int>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pair of ints has type [std::pair](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair)`<int, int>` ( also [std::tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple)`<int, int>` in C++11 and later )

```
typedef boost::bimap<boost::bimaps::set_of<int>,boost::bimaps::multiset_of<std::pair<int, int > > > bimap;
bimap numbers;
numbers.insert({1, {1, 5}});
numbers.insert({2, {1, 1}});
```

Note the extra {} in the inserts

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can search anything by using an iterator, but how can I get key and its value by using `at(1) or at(2)`

Comment: `key` and `value` from which side of the bimap? you can search with e.g. `numbers.right.find({1, 1});` to get 2

Comment: don't want to search. I know my key is there and i want to search something from left like `numbers.left.at(1)` or from right

Comment: in the given example, you get a `std::pair<int, int>` from that, with the value `1, 5`. I don't know what you want if that isn't it

Comment: Ya exactly . `numbers.left.at(1)` should give `1,5` and `numbers.right.at(1,5)` is 1

Comment: Have you tried that with my example? Those are the results I expect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133912/discussion-between-caleth-and-awaitedone).